# Combine old log entries from git log

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a project with the following log

```
commit10
commit09
commit08
commit07
commit06
commit05
...
commit01
```

I want convert commits from 01 to 08 to only one commit. the result I want is

```
commit10
commit09
commitXX
```

where the commit message is something like 'initial commit' or something. How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) command, or interactively (which is nice) as `git rebase -i`.  In particular, this would be a 'squash' --- to combine some commits into others.

Here, the best way to do this might be: `git rebase -i HEAD~10` to look at the 10 most recent commits.  You can then use the interactive prompt to select which ones to `'s'quash` and which to `'p'ick` (i.e. preserve).

In your case this might look like:

```
p SHA10 commit10
p SHA09 commit09
s SHA08 commit08
s SHA10 commit07
...
s SHA01 commit01
```

Then it will prompt you to change the commit message - if you want to.

If you want to undo your rebase, use `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD` --- rebase saves the previous state to `ORIG_HEAD`.

Comment: Could you please add a example using the hypothetical commits of my question